# Access version 2000 & 2013 SQL pull latest date, MAX doesn't work

Tags: date, ms-access

I have a table that needs to pull the latest date from different categories and the date might not always be filled out. I have tried to use MAX, MIN etc. it has not worked.

```
e.g. ID    1st Game Date  2nd Game Date  3rd Game Date
     Joe       6/1/16         missing       missing
     Anna       missing       7/2/16        7/6/16
     Rita      missing        7/31/16       missing
```

Needs to Return:

```
  ID       Date
  Joe      6/1/16
  Anna     7/6/16
  Rita     7/31/16
```

I do have this sql that works well but it requires that all the dates get filled in other wise it doesn't return the latest date:

```
ApptDate: Switch([Pt1stApptDate]>=[2ndApptDate] And [Pt1stApptDate]>=
[3rdApptDate],[Pt1stApptDate],[2ndApptDate]>=[Pt1stApptDate] And [2ndApptDate]>=
[3rdApptDate],[2ndApptDate],[3rdApptDate]>=[Pt1stApptDate] And [3rdApptDate]>=
[2ndApptDate],[3rdApptDate])
```

Much appreciation in advance for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nz function:

```
ApptDate: Switch(Nz([Pt1stApptDate],0)>=Nz([2ndApptDate],0) And
Nz([Pt1stApptDate],0)>= Nz([3rdApptDate],0), Nz([Pt1stApptDate],0),
Nz([2ndApptDate],0)>=Nz([Pt1stApptDate],0) And Nz([2ndApptDate],0)>=
Nz([3rdApptDate],0),Nz([2ndApptDate],0),
Nz([3rdApptDate],0)>=Nz([Pt1stApptDate],0) And Nz([3rdApptDate],0)>=
Nz([2ndApptDate],0),Nz([3rdApptDate],0))
```

Having said that, your table design is incorrect.
You should be storing each ApptDate per ID in a separate row:

```
ApptID  ID  ApptDate    ApptNr
1   Joe     6/1/2016    1
2   Anna    7/2/2016    2
3   Anna    7/6/2016    3
4   Rita    7/31/2016   2
```

whereas ApptID is an autonumber and ApptNr is a sequence per ID (what you seem to call a category).

Comment: Thank you soooo much the Nz function worked perfectly ;)

Comment: Thumbs up for my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

When you are having problems writing what should be simple queries (SQL DML) then you should consider you may have design flaws (in your SQL DDL).

The missing values are causing you to avoid the `MAX` set function and compels you to handle nulls in queries (note the `NZ()` function will cause errors outside of the Access UI). Better to model missing data by simply not adding a row to a table. Think about it: you want the smallest amount of data possible in your database, you can infer the remainder e.g. if Joe was not gaming on 1 Jan and 2 Jan and 3 Jan and 4 Jan etc then simply don't add anything to your database for all these dates.

The following SQL DDL requires ANSI-92 Query Mode (but you can create the same tables/views using the Access GUI tools):

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance
( gamer_name VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL REFERENCES Gamers ( gamer_name ),
  game_sequence NOT NULL CHECK ( game_sequence BETWEEN 1 AND 3 )
  game_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ( game_date, game_sequence ) );


INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES ( 'Joe',  1, '2016-06-01' );
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES ( 'Anna', 2, '2016-07-02' );
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES ( 'Anna', 3, '2016-07-06' );
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES ( 'Rita', 1, '2016-07-31' );


CREATE VIEW MostRecentAttendance
AS
SELECT gamer_name, MAX ( game_date ) AS game_date
  FROM Attendance
 GROUP
    BY gamer_name;


SELECT * 
  FROM Attendance a
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM MostRecentAttendance r
                 WHERE r.gamer_name = a.gamer_name
                       AND r.game_date = a.game_date );
```

To find the missing sequence values for players, create a table of all possible sequence numbers `{ 1, 2, 3 }` to which you can 'anti-join' (e.g. `NOT EXISTS`).